# django {% url %} NoReverseMatch at /

Tags: python, django, url

my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,include,re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index,name='index'),
    re_path(r'(?P<title> [\w]+)/$',views.article_details,name='details')
]
```

my views.py

```
def article_details(request,title):
    return render(request, 'guestbook/article_detail.html')
```

my html:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <h1><a href="{% url 'details' %}" > hello</h1>

        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

the error is NoReverseMatch at /guestbook/hello/
Error during template rendering

```
Reverse for 'details' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['guestbook\\/(?P<title>[\\w]+)/$']
```

What am I doing wrong here ? I can't seem to figure that out..please help

Comment: `{% url 'details' %}` requires title

Comment: the right code is <h1><a href="{% url 'details' title=article.title %}" > {{ article.title }}</h1>,thank for help : ) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your html template-
`<h1><a href="{% url 'details' title="put_here_any_exiting_title_in_your_db" %}" > hello</h1>`

Your details url expecting title parameter so you have to pass it there.